# Add row to dataset with lookup

Tags: r, dataframe, lookup

I am new to Rstudios and I have a question regarding my dataset. I now have three colums and I want to add data that I can find in another dataset. The dataset I have right now looks like this (example):

| dummy | year bought | current year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1620 | 1621 |
| 0 | 1620 | 1622 |
| 0 | 1620 | 1623 |
| 1 | 1620 | 1624 |
| 0 | 1622 | 1623 |
| 0 | 1622 | 1624 |
| 0 | 1622 | 1625 |
| 0 | 1622 | 1626 |
| 0 | 1622 | 1627 |
| 1 | 1622 | 1628 |

The other dataset contains a price index for every year. Like this (example):

| Year | Price index |
| --- | --- |
| 1620 | 100 |
| 1621 | 102 |
| 1622 | 99 |
| 1623 | 105 |
| 1624 | 111 |
| 1625 | 116 |

Now, I want to add a 4th column to my original dataset, containing the log difference of the price index between the 'year bought' and the 'current year'. I'm guessing this would be done best with some sort of lookup, however I am new to R and can't find how to do it. Any help is appreciated!

P.S. the variable 'year bought' is a integer, and the variable 'year' in the price index dataset is a double; I don't know whether that changes anything or not but just to let you know!

Comment: It's best to post/paste your data using `dput(YourData)`, at least in addition to your data shown.

Comment: The dataset is much larger and runs from 1620-1811, this was just an example

Comment: Hey @MartinGal, I don't exactly know what you mean by that. Do I past it here? By just editing the post or how do you mean that?

Comment: `dput(YourData)` returns a `structure...`-output in R. You can edit your question and attach that specific output to your question. A person, that wants to help you, can copy that `structure(...)` part into R and get's an example of your data. If your data is very large, you can use `dput(head(YourData))` to just get the first few lines or `dput(head(YourData, n = 25))` for the first 25 lines. `YourData` is - of course - the name of your data object in R.

Answer (score 3):

We create a named vector and use that to match with the 'current_year', 'year_bought' to get the 'Price_index', get the difference and take the `log`

```
nm1 <- with(df2, setNames(Price_index, Year))
out <- transform(df1, diff = log(abs(nm1[as.character(current_year)] - 
           nm1[as.character(year_bought)])))
```

-output

```
out
   dummy year_bought current_year      diff
1      0        1620         1621 0.6931472
2      0        1620         1622 0.0000000
3      0        1620         1623 1.6094379
4      1        1620         1624 2.3978953
5      0        1622         1623 1.7917595
6      0        1622         1624 2.4849066
7      0        1622         1625 2.8332133
8      0        1622         1626        NA
9      0        1622         1627        NA
10     1        1622         1628        NA
```

The `NA`s are those where the lookup example ('df2') didn't have the 'Year'

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(dummy = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L), year_bought = c(1620L, 1620L, 1620L, 1620L, 1622L, 1622L, 
1622L, 1622L, 1622L, 1622L), current_year = c(1621L, 1622L, 1623L, 
1624L, 1623L, 1624L, 1625L, 1626L, 1627L, 1628L)), 
    class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))

df2 <- structure(list(Year = 1620:1625, Price_index = c(100L, 102L, 
99L, 105L, 111L, 116L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: I indeed meant to say 4th column, changet it now

Comment: @BeginnerinRstudio thanks, in the exxample the lookup didn't have 1626 to 1628.  Thus, the log will be NA

Comment: Yeah, the dataset is actually much larger and runs up to 1811, this was just an example :)

Comment: @BeginnerinRstudio ok.  Please check the solution posted.  Thanks

Comment: Something is going wrong, when I run this, I just get a value named 'nm1', which just contains every year, with the price index, basically the same as I already have as my second dataframe.

Comment: @BeginnerinRstudio Can you try this on the data I showed in  my post which is reproducible.  Please note that I replaced the spaces in column names to `_`

Comment: I then get the exact same thing, df1 and df2 both don't change. I only get a new value called 'nm1', which contains almost the exact same data as 'df2' only with different headers

Comment: @BeginnerinRstudio Have you noticed that I assign the output to a different object `out` so that your original dataset won't change.  If you want to change the original object, just change the `out <-` to `df1 <-`

Comment: Aaahhh I didn't notice. I'm so close right now to getting it. I still get one error tho, Error: unexpected symbol in:
"                                         nm1[(Year_bought)])).  I actually notice right now that both 'year_bought' as 'year' in df2 numeric values are, so maybe something goes wrong with the 'as caracter' ?? i have no idea tho

Comment: @BeginnerinRstudio Is this error based on the same data in my post.  I see that your column name is `Year_bought` whereas I used `year_bought` and also if you check my solution, I convert it to `character` with `as.character`.

Comment: No, with your data it worked perfectly! Now I just need to get the same for my own data ;)

Comment: @BeginnerinRstudio ok, I see some difference in your code.  Probably that is the case of issue. i.e. You need to convert to `character` with `as.character`

Comment: Heey I tried the solution from Martin Gal and that one worked aswell! Thank you both so much, it is late here now, tomorrow I will try to finish your solution aswell, thanks!

Comment: I followed the whole process here.  What I have learned is that akrun is a shining example when it comes to help others! Thanks master!

Answer (score 2):

Another option could be

```r
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  left_join(df2, by=c("year_bought" = "Year")) %>%
  left_join(df2, by=c("current_year" = "Year")) %>%
  mutate(diff = log(abs(Price_index.y - Price_index.x))) %>%
  select(-Price_index.x, -Price_index.y)
```

which returns the same output as @akrun's solution.

We are using two left joins to attach the price indices for `year_bought` and `current_year` to `df1`. Then we calculate the logarithmic difference.

Comment: akrun's solution is far more sophisticated. I'm not a big fan of multiple left joining.